# having problems with for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table with numbers but they are stored as string so I am trying to use the function parseFloat to convert it into a table of ints. However, no matter how I do the for loops it gives me a blank table. I can parse the row and it will give me a single int. I can parse a single int as well but cant seem to parse a row or the table. here is what I have so far. This is just trying to convert one row. I tried two for loops for the entire table but that didn't work either. thanks.

```
 var c =[];
    var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($try, true)); ?>');  
       for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
       {
         for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
         { 
         c [j][i] = parseFloat(entries[j][i]);
         }
       }
alert(c);
```

here is entries json encodes [["-248","-163","-455","-1413","-1294","-1296","-1089"],["-172","-219","-1186","-1368","-1480","-1079","-845"],["-98","-198","-703","-996","-1100","-585","-616"],["-116","-241","-498","-642","-704","-354","-430"],["-137","-117","-264","-525","-533","-269","-476"],["-12","87","-257","-463","-551","-302","-535"],["170","61","-250","-472","-659","-220","-605"],["159","96","-234","-513","-617","-196","-710"],["185","117","-272","-521","-610","-258","-798"],["208","95","-234","-534","-696","-280","-854"],["192","151","-188","-641","-739","-279","-957"],["249","223","-235","-684","-763","-339","-978"]]

Comment: i is undefined, set `var i = 0` in your loop

Comment: `for (var j = 0; i < 12; j++)` That `i` should be a `j`.

Comment: it is saying uncaught type error cannot set property 0 to undefined after parseFloat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize the second dimension of your array to also be an array.  As it stands now, `c[j]` is just a single value so you can't do `c[j][i]` on it.  There is also an error in your first `for` loop where you need to compare the value of `j`, not `i`.  See this fixed code:

```
var c = [];
var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($try, true)); ?>');  
   for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
   {
     c[j] = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
     { 
         c [j][i] = parseFloat(entries[j][i]);
     }
   }
alert(c);
```

Comment: yes that would do it. thanks so much. didn't realize I had to do that. makes so much sense now

Comment: @AustenNovis - rather than your hard coded lengths, you could use the `.length` property of the `entries` arrays.  That would make your code more robust if the data is ever edited and is a better practice in general.

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop `for (var j = 0; i < 12; j++)`, you are using `i` for iteration but it is undefined and it should be `j` instead of `i`

```
var c =[];
var entries = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($try, true)); ?>');  
for (var j = 0; j < entries.length ; j++)
{
    c[j] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < entries[i].length ; i++)
    {          
       c [j][i] = parseFloat(entries[j][i]);
    }
}
```